# Order child rows after parent row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a MySQL database with a table that contains data like so:

```
ID | name    | data  | ParentId
1  | somename| 435   | 0
2  | name2   | sample| 0
3  | child   | sample| 1
...
```

I am trying to write a query that gets me all the data from this table and places each child/children after its parent.

Example:

```
1. somename | 435
1.1. child  | sample
...
```

Is that possible? If not with a query, can I do it with PHP (it's what I'm using for my back-end).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel as tagged in the question.
In models, define relation as

User.php

```
public function Child()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','ParentId');
}

public function Parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','ParentId');
}
```

and in controller, do

```
  public function allUsers(){
      $users = User::with('Child')->get();
      return $users 
   }
```

result would be

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "somename",
    "ParentId": 0,
    "child": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "child",
        "ParentId": 1
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "ParentId": 0,
    "child": []
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "child",
    "ParentId": 1,
    "child": []
}]
```

Comment: if you are loading directly to view use:-  return view('list',compact('users'));

Comment: This does not work. I think the relationship is wrong... a child can have just 1 parent, while a parent can have many children. Also, the FK appears wrong.

Comment: @Mihail...   with the above code i got this result , pls verify [{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "somename",
 "ParentId": 0,
 "child": [{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "child",
  "ParentId": 1
 }]
}, {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "name2",
 "ParentId": 0,
 "child": []
}, {
 "id": 3,
 "name": "child",
 "ParentId": 1,
 "child": []
}]

Comment: I still think that all can be made in SQL must be ! among others for simplification and speed

Answer (score 0):

### MySQL solution

**You can make it directly in MySQL Query**, here is an example modified for you of the solution I use myself.

**1. SORTING BY PARENT**

For sorting by parent (and make chaptering yourself in PHP/Laravel as you expect in your question), modify your query adding the following `IF` statement and modifying `ORDER BY` :

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, 
    IF(T1.`parentId` > 0, 
        (SELECT `name` FROM `table` T2 WHERE T2.`ID` = T1.`parentId`), 
        T1.`title`
    ) AS `parentName`,
FROM `table` T1 
ORDER BY `parentName` ASC, `name` ASC
```

---

**2. CHAPTERING (advanced use)**

If you want to make the chaptering directly in MySQL, it's possible. I thinked on that and make for you an advanced Query.

First, to use the `ID` is not a good idea because this one will be unique so for example for the *chapter 3.* you cannot start again to *3.1, 3.2, ...* for sub-chapters.

**MySQL table**

So, let's create a new column in your table called `sorting` (it's like chapter number AND sub-chapter number) :

```
ID | name    | data  | ParentId | sorting
1  | somename| 435   | 0        | 1
2  | name2   | sample| 0        | 2
3  | child   | sample| 1        | 1
```

**SQL**

In your query, we two new columns dynamically :

1. a new column called `parentTitle` and `ORDER BY` these new column first to have sub-chapter under chapter in the list,
2. and create another one column called `treeName` with use of `CONCAT()` which contains all the nomenclature you want to get.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT 
    T1.*,
    IF(T1.`parentId` > 0, 
        (SELECT `name` FROM `table` T2 WHERE T2.`ID` = T1.`parentId`), 
        T1.`title`
    ) AS `parentName`,
    IF(T1.`parentId` > 0, 
        CONCAT((SELECT `sorting` FROM `table` T3 WHERE T3.`ID` = T1.`parentId`), '.', T1.`sorting`, '. ', T1.`title`),
        CONCAT(T1.`sorting`, '. ', T1.`title`)
    ) AS `treeName`
FROM `table` T1 
GROUP BY T1.`ID`
ORDER BY 
    `parentName` ASC,
    `sorting` ASC
```

**PHP**

After that you can with simply show your list like this :

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['treeName'];
}
```